# Loading csv files by url breaks down after two files without obvious reason

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, url, try-catch

I am trying to load some `.csv` files from www2.census.gov as follows:

```
# Create the numbers to replace in the download link:
download_number <- c("01", "02", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10")
dn <- seq(from = 11, to = 56, by = 1)
download_number <- append(download_number, dn)

# Load the url's
county_controls_2010_urllist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(download_number)) {
  url_holder[[i]] <- glue::glue("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2000-2010/intercensal/county/co-est00int-alldata-{download_number[[i]]}.csv")
  tryCatch({
    county_controls_2010_list[[i]] <- read.csv(url_holder) # https://www.programmingr.com/examples/read-csv-web/
    if (i==1000) stop("stop")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})  
}
```

The code for some reason breaks down after two files. I first thought it was because file `03` does not exist, which is why I tried to put the `tryCatch` in. But now I just get an error for every file after nr2. The errors are as follows:

```
ERROR : invalid 'description' argument 
ERROR : invalid 'description' argument 
...
ERROR : invalid 'description' argument 
ERROR : invalid 'description' argument
```

I have checked the link location for the 2nd and 3rd file, but they look identical.

```
https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2000-2010/intercensal/county/co-est00int-alldata-02.csv
https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2000-2010/intercensal/county/co-est00int-alldata-04.csv
```

Could someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
file_url <- sprintf("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2000-2010/intercensal/county/co-est00int-alldata-%s.csv", download_number)

purrr::map_df(file_url, function(x) tryCatch(read.csv(x), 
                                    error = function(e) message('skipping ', x), 
                                    warning = function(w) {})) -> result
result
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Any idea why my code does not work? There is a typo in your answer by the way: `purrr:` in stead of `purrr::`, but I cannot fix it because there is a six character minimum.

Comment: Thanks..corrected. I am not exactly sure why your code doesn't work. Did you try restarting R and trying it again?